# Java loop through list and back again and so on... what list type to use?

Tags: java, android, list, loops

What would be a good list structure to use when I want to loop trough it and back again and so on? I'm now using a extended `ArrayList` with a custom method for looping it forward and backward etc.

Does Java (Android) offer a list type that I can use without extending it's behavior?

If not, what would be the best way to code a list for this use-case?

My current code looks a bit like this:

```
if(!back){
    if(hasNext()){
        return next();
    } else {
        back = true;
        return previous();
    }
} else {
    if(hasPrevious()){
        return previous();
    } else {
        back = false;
        return next();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's bad about your implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is exactly what you're looking for. It's default [`iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29) is a forward iterator,  but it also provides a [`descendingIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#descendingIterator%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Use LinkedList for forward as well as backward navigation.This one is most suitable for this.

Comment: LinkedList in android does not offer hasNext and other methods, are you telling me that i should use the listIterator?

Comment: List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
  Iterator<String>iterator =list.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext())
  {
   System.out.println(iterator.next());
  }

Answer (score 0):

With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), you can just do

```
for (E forwardElement : list) {
  ...
}
for (E backwardElement : Lists.reverse(list)) {
  // Lists.reverse returns a view, so it's free
  ...
}
```

or if you want to do them both in a single loop,

```
for (E element : Iterables.concat(list, Lists.reverse(list))) {
  ...
}
```

(Internally, this just wraps your `ListIterator` and reverses its direction, but it's really straightforward to use it like this.)

Comment: Could be useful, but including this lib in my android project would be overkill. And extracting only the stuff i need from this lib could get pretty complicated. But still useful answer.

Comment: Not complicated at all, with e.g. http://proguard.sourceforge.net/.  Guava provides a quick guide [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava)

Answer (score 0):

You could use any type of List you like.  You can write a specialized `ForwardAndBackIterator` that implements `Iterator` and encapsulates the behavior you want.  Add it in below.

```
public class ForwardAndBackIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private List<T> list;

    public ForwardAndBackIterator<T>(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
    }

    public T next() {
    }

    public void remove(T value) {
    }
}
```